# Trying to find mule esb 3.7.X apikit api document

Tags: mule, apikit

I'm trying to find mule esb 3.7.x apikit api pages on mule documentation, but no luck. could someone point me please

I'm looking for this package **org.mule.module.apikit.exception** classes

Answer (score 0):

You can find the 3.x source code on Github including the exception package: https://github.com/mulesoft/apikit/tree/apikit-3.x/mule-module-apikit/src/main/java/org/mule/module/apikit/exception

Answer (score 0):

The documentation pages seem to have changed and now refer to mayor version only (3.x instead of different pages for 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9): https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/3.x/